# spring cloud stream support json header?(in the body)

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, amazon-kinesis

Our all consumer application use `spring-cloud-stream`.
But our one big producer application(legacy..) can't use `spring-cloud-stream` because spring boot version is `1.4`.

We tried to send message with `kinesis` message broker.
We want to send custom headers through kinesis, but kinesis doesn't support sending headers as you know.
So we decided to send a header in `body`.

```
{
  "header": {
    ~~
  }
  "payload": {
    ~~
  }
}
```

But `spring-cloud-stream` can't receive header in `body`.
We thought we could receive a header in `body` using the `embeddedHeaders` option(in spring-cloud-stream).

```
{channelName}:
    destination: local-event
    consumer:
        header-mode: embeddedHeaders
```

But... it's not working.

So.. is there any way to receive header in `body`?
Or we have to select another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embedded header values are individual JSON snippets, but they are encoded into the message using a binary format - see [EmbeddedHeaderUtils](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-stream/latest/org/springframework/cloud/stream/binder/EmbeddedHeaderUtils.html).

> Encodes requested headers into payload with format

```
0xff, n(1), [ [lenHdr(1), hdr, lenValue(4), value] ... ].
```

> The 0xff indicates this new format; n is number of headers (max 255); for each header, the name length (1 byte) is followed by the name, followed by the value length (int) followed by the value (json).